# how do I check if a property exists in an object?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Apologize. I'm fairly certain this is a rather novice question; however, here it goes! Thanks for any hints in advance :)

I have the below function in my app, and running the app now throws the error "TypeError: parameters.includes is not a function." What does this error mean? Does the if statement require a function? How should I set up this conditional?

```
function handleApiAiAction(sender, action, responseText, contexts, parameters, response) {
    switch (action) {
        case "job-search":
            console.log(parameters);
            if (parameters.includes("quickreply")) {
                console.log("it worked");
            } else {
                let replies = response.result.fulfillment.messages[0].replies;
                let title = response.result.fulfillment.messages[0].title;
                sendQuickReply(sender, title, replies);
                console.log("it didn't work");
            }
            break;
        default:
            //unhandled action, just send back the text
            sendTextMessage(sender, responseText);
    }
}
```

console.log('parameters') gives me:

```
{ quickreply: 'quickreply' }
```

[some edits :)]

Comment: Read the error, the object does not have function `includes`... perhaps you meant `parameters.quickreply.includes("quickreply")` or `"quickreply" in parameters`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{ quickreply: 'quickreply' }` does not contain the object member `includes: function() {}` (nor does the [`Object.prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype)).

What it looks like you're trying to do is check if the object contains the property `quickreply`, so you should do something like this:

```
if('quickreply' in parameters) {
  // do stuff
}
```

There are other methods you can use, too, like [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty). They each have their own nuances, but `in` looks like it should work in your case.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Obviously i'm still learning the basics. I was upset to see this question was downvoted a fair bit. Should I not be asking basic questions on here? Are there better places to ask such questions, in your experience?

Comment: @taylorhamcheese no problem. I don't think it deserves down votes, but I think people were upset 1) because the error was clear ("includes" is not a function), and 2) you should try to narrow down your question. For example, ask "how do I check if a property exists in an object?" (That was the actual question, but instead I had to figure out first what the real question was). Does that make sense what I'm saying? Hopefully that helps.

Comment: @taylorhamcheese unfortunately people tend to hop on the "down vote" train.

Comment: @taylorhamcheese it's perfectly okay to ask basic questions, just do your best to make the question as clear as you can :)

Comment: Thank you for the clarity :)

I'm still not 100% clear what my underlying misunderstanding was. I understood the error to mean "this if function requires a function, but 'parameters.includes' is not a function"--which of course made 0 sense to me haha.

Is the lesson that includes cannot be called on an array?

Comment: @taylorhamcheese `includes` does not exist on the Object prototype. Also, `{}` is an object-literal, not an array.

Comment: @taylorhamcheese I suggest going back to the basics and learning about JavaScript prototypal inheritance and the basic data structures (and their names). This should help provide you with some clarity :) for example, there's quite a big difference between an object-literal and an array.

Answer (score 3):

`includes` isn't a valid method on an object. You could use in:

`if ('quickreply' in parameters)`